# How to highlight parsed JSON data in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, frontend

I want to highlight specific text from parsed JSON response and to SUM the number of specific status results and present it inside the HTML file as well.

For example - highlight in another color all the parsed data that contains "frozen" but only this word, not all the parsed data chunk.

Also, Count of all the frozen word per env and present the total 
in the

tag.

**my code:**

```
async function rangersChecking() {
    let index;
    const hostsRang = [env1 + rangers, env2 + rangers, env3 + rangers, env4 + rangers, env5 + rangers, env6 + rangers];
    let lengthVal = hostsRang.length;
    for (let hostIndxRang = 0; hostIndxRang < lengthVal; hostIndxRang++) {
        index = hostIndxRang;
        let url = hostsRang[hostIndxRang];
        let response = await fetch(url, getFetchConfig());
        let avatars = await response.json();
        for (avatar of avatars) {
            const tagSpan = document.getElementById('rangers_' + hostIndxRang);
            const avatarStringified = JSON.stringify(
                Object.assign({}, {id: avatar.avatar_id, status: getAvatarStatuses(avatar)}),
                null,
                4
            );
            // tagSpan.innerText += avatarStringified.replace(/[\{\}]/g, "");
            tagSpan.innerText += avatarStringified.replace(/[\{\}]|"/g, "");
        }
    }
}

function getFetchConfig() {
    return {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow',
        agent: null,
        headers: {"TOKEN": token, "Content-Type": "text/plain"},
        timeout: 10000
    };
}

function getAvatarStatuses(avatar) {
    let result = "";

    for(network of avatar.social_networks) {
        result += `${network.domain}: ${network.status}`;
    }

    return result;
}
```

HTML File:

```
<tr>
    <th id="total">Total frozen: <p id="total_env1"></p></th>
</tr>
<!-- Rangers Status- ENV 1 -->
<td id="rangers">
    <div id="rangersTable"><pre><span id="rangers_0"></span></pre></div>
</td>
```

**Technical info:**

JS ES6,
Node JS.

Comment: You provided a goal but no specific problem in achieving that goal. What is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.. I've tried a couple of attempts but all of them are not achevied my goal.